# Possible to have one checkBox CheckedChanged event for all checkBoxes?

Tags: c#

I have a form that has ten checkBoxes.  They all have the exact same code in them and by that I mean a single call to a method.  I'm just curious is there a way to have a single generic CheckedChanged event?

```
private void checkBox_one_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    enableImage();
}

private void checkBox_two_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    enableImage();
}
```

I've got ten of those.  Is there anyway to simplify this so I can just have a single event that captures them all?

Comment: Why don't you just attach the same event handler to all of your checkboxes?

Comment: You only need to attach the same event in all of your checkboxes

Comment: Just give all of them 1 change event

Comment: use the same eventHandler

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is using the Form Designer and has no clue how to wire up an event handler in code.

Comment: What is this? I guess ASP.NET. Then you just need to use `OnCheckedChanged="checkBox_CheckedChanged"` on all your checkboxes. And it must be `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: What framework are you talking about?

Comment: @Dan-o, well Dan, since I'm a novice programmer that doesn't have 20+ years of programming experience you would be correct in your assumption.  I'm still learning many of the finer points.  Please cut me a little slack.  I graduated at the top of my CS class but obviously I mostly know only theory.  I don't know all the in's and out's of VS.net c#.

Comment: @GrawCube, Thank you for that suggestion.  I was wondering if I could do that.  It works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Use the `sender` parameter cast to `CheckBox` to know just which has changed!

Comment: @JohnJenkins: It would serve you well to take people's comments as constructive and not get defensive.  In this particular case my comments were not directed at you, but was an observation about you directed at the people helping you, so they could help you better.  A defensive attitude will NOT help you get or keep a job.

Comment: @Dan-o, you can understand how your comment can easily be misconstrued, right?

Answer (score 5):

You only need to attach the same event to all of checkboxes:

```
        <CheckBox Name="_chkOne" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding 
                  Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <CheckBox Name="_chkTwo" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding 
                  Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select the check boxes in question, press <kbd>F4</kbd> and assign the event to all check boxes at once.